# accessing cell metadata from jinja2 template

Tags: jinja2, jupyter-notebook

I try to create a custom latex template to create PDF output from a jupyter notebook. I'd like to cancel cells output when cells are tagged in a special way. For example, let say I edit a metadata for a given cell (from the notebook/"Edit metadata") and add this sub-json:

```
[...]
"tpl": {
    "view_in": true,
    "view_out": false
},
[...]
```

Then, I tried to derive the template by using the `cell` variable, as briefly shown in http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#Templates-that-use-cell-metadata:

```
% ((*- extends 'report.tplx' -*))
% Disable input cells
((* block input_group *))
((* endblock input_group *))
% disable output if required from metadata
((* if cell['metadata'].get('tpl', {}).get('view_out', True) == true *))
    ((* block output_group  *))
    ((* endblock output_group  *))
((* endif *))
```

But jinja2 complains when I try to generate my PDF:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to pdf C4_RevD.ipynb --template=tpl.tpl
    [...]
    jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'cell' is undefine
```

How can a access to cell metdata from a jinja2 template?

***[Edit] versions used:***

```
Python: 2.7.6
jupyter: 4.0.6
jupyter notebook: 4.1.0
jinja2: 2.8
```

Comment: The `cell` variable is only available in `any_cell` blocks and blocks inside those. So they code you're adding is inside out - you need to check the metadata inside the `output_group` block, and decide whether or not to give it contents.

Comment: @ThomasK: thanks for your tip, it works. If you would write a proper answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell variable is only available in any_cell blocks and blocks inside those ([template structure docs](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#Template-structure)). So they code you're adding is inside out - you need to check the metadata inside the output_group block, and decide whether or not to give it contents. Something like this:

```
((* block output_group  *))
    ((* if cell['metadata'].get('tpl', {}).get('view_out', True) == true *))
        ((* super() *))
    ((* endif *))
((* endblock output_group  *))
```